# Insert background image using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I've just started using FFMpeg and I'm trying to create a video slideshow from images with a background image. The background would not change only the image.

Similar to this:

[image]

I have the following

```
"ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 \
-start_number 1 \
-i "C:/test/%03d.jpg" \
-c:v libx264 \
-r 30 "C:/test/video.mp4"
```

And that works perfectly to create slideshow with the pictures but when I try to add a background image for each picture using the following command (overlay).

```
"ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 \
-start_number 1 \
-i "C:/test/%03d.jpg" \
-vf 'movie=C:/test/bg.jpg [over], [in][over] overlay'
-c:v libx264 \
-r 30 "C:/test/video.mp4"
```

This is my error log:

```
    ffmpeg version N-69587-g15a8846 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-

    bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
      libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
      libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5.  9.103 /  5.  9.103
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Trailing options were found on the commandline.
    Input #0, image2, from 'C:/test/%03d.jpg':
      Duration: 00:00:15.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 768x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], 0.20 fps, 0.20 tbr, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc
    At least one output file must be specified
```

Update from answer:

```
<cfscript>
    try {
        runtime = createObject("java", "java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime();
        command = '#ffmpegPath#' &
        ' -loop 1' &
        ' -framerate 1' &
        ' -i "C:/test/bg.jpg"' & 
        ' -framerate 1/5 -start_number 1' &
        ' -i "C:/test/%03d.jpg"' & 
        ' -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p"' &
        ' -c:v libx264' &
        ' -r 30' &
        ' -movflags +faststart' &
        ' -shortest' &
        ' "C:/test/out.mp4"'; 
        process = runtime.exec(#command#);
        results.errorLogSuccess = processStream(process.getErrorStream(), errorLog);
        results.resultLogSuccess = processStream(process.getInputStream(), resultLog);
        results.exitCode = process.waitFor();
    }
    catch(exception e) {
        results.status = e;    
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: You're missing one backslash after the `-vf` line. That's why ffmpeg tells you that there are trailing options (`-vf`) and no output file. But even then it wouldn't work, as you need a complex filtergraph, and you need to position the overlay correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Slideshow with static image background

[image: pug life]

You don't need to use the `movie` source filter, and use `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf`.

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 \
-framerate 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-framerate 1/5 \
-i "C:/test/%03d.jpg" \
-filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 \
-r 30 \
-movflags +faststart \
output.mp4
```

- `format=yuv420p` will ensure a widely compatible "pixel format" or chroma subsampling scheme which is useful to add when using `libx264`.
- `-movflags +faststart` will relocate some data after encoding is finished which will allow viewers to begin playback before the file is completely downloaded. Useful for example if you're hosting it yourself and putting it on a web site.

## With audio

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 \
-framerate 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-framerate 1/5 \
-i "C:/test/%03d.jpg" \
-i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 \
-r 30 \
-c:a aac -strict experimental \
-b:a 192k \
-movflags +faststart \
-shortest
output.mp4
```

## With text

Text can be added with the `drawtext` filter.

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 \
-framerate 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-framerate 1/5 \
-i "C:/test/%03d.jpg" \
-i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,drawtext=fontsize=30:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 \
-r 30 \
-c:a aac -strict experimental \
-b:a 192k \
-movflags +faststart \
-shortest \
output.mp4
```

See the [`drawtext` filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for many more options.

## With a border

The [`drawbox` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) can be used to draw a white border around the overlaid image. Notice that I started naming the inputs and outputs from each filter, then I referenced the final filter results with `-map`.

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 \
-framerate 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-framerate 1/5 \
-i "C:/test/%03d.jpg" \
-i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]drawbox=t=5:c=white[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,drawtext=fontsize=30:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]"
-map 0:a
-c:v libx264 \
-r 30 \
-c:a aac -strict experimental \
-b:a 192k \
-movflags +faststart \
-shortest \
output.mp4
```

### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer.  I've updated my question with the answer you gave me but when I run the command it never ends and the size of the file just gets bigger. I have to kill the process. Can you check if I made a mistake (see Update from answer).

Comment: @Yannick Does it work as expected if you run `ffmpeg` manually via command line?

Comment: Yes @LordNeckbeard as you can see http://screencast.com/t/LYqd0KNoMjX

Comment: @Yannick. I forgot to use the `shortest=1` option in overlay. This is needed because I made you loop your background image, and by default overlay will **not** end when the shortest input ends. Answer has been updated.

Comment: got this error: `[Parsed_drawtext_1 @ 0x26b4000] Could not load font "FreeSerif.ttf": cannot open resource
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x263fa00] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontsize=30:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text=hello world:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`

Comment: @NineCattoRules You need to point `fontfile` option to a font file available on your computer. You may need to use the full path, such as `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks for helping out with ffmpeg media queries. Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192759/ffmpeg-add-background-image-during-the-process-of-video-creation

Comment: @Killer I was away for several weeks. Looks like you got an answer.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i have almost done like you however there are some image drop. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520915/ffmpeg-frame-drop-when-merging-a-image-sequence-and-overlaying-during-video-crea